# replace single digits which surrounding non-digits with a space using java

Tags: java, regex

I want to replace single digits which surrounding alpha charactors[a-zA-Z] with a space in a string as follows.

```
"Foo 12 Bar" => "Foo 12 Bar" //1 and 2 shouldn’t be replaced
"Foo12Bar"   => "Foo12Bar"   // 1 and 2 shouldn’t be replaced
"Foo1Bar"    => "Foo Bar"    //1 shouldn’t be replaced
"Foo2Bar"    => "Foo Bar"    //2 shouldn’t be replaced
"Foo 1Bar"   => "Foo 1Bar"   //1 shouldn’t be replaced(space @ left side)
```

any help on this?

Comment: why the last example is not replaced?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this pattern with a space as replacement:

```
(?<=[^0-9\\s])[0-9](?=[^0-9\\s])
```

`(?<=...)` and `(?=...)` are respectively a lookbehind and a lookahead assertion. This is only checks and the content described between these parenthesis are not a part of the match result. So, the characters before and after are not replaced.

Answer (score 3):

You can try regex like this :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s1= "Foo1Bar";
        String s2 = "Foo11bar";
        String s3 = "foo1bar2";
        String regex = "(?<=[a-zA-Z])\\d(?=[a-zA-Z])";// positive look-behind and positive look-ahead for characters a-z A-Z surrounding digit
        System.out.println(s1.replaceAll(regex, " "));
        System.out.println(s2.replaceAll(regex, " "));
        System.out.println(s3.replaceAll(regex, " "));
    }
```

O/P :

```
Foo Bar
Foo11bar
foo bar2
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a regex `replaceAll` call on the string object. Replace `(?<!\d)(?<! )\d(?!\d)(?! )` with an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

```
input.replaceAll("([^\\d])\\d([^\\d])", "$1$2");
```

The regex used matches a digit that is surrounded with any non-digit character. So the whole match is just replaced by the character before, and after, the single digit character that matched "\d".

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged here on SO because while they may strictly answer the question, they don't provide much insight to the asker or future users who stumble across the question.  Would encourage you to provide an explanation as to why your solution answer's the OP's question

Comment: Will not work in case of string like `a1b2c` because `b` will be consumed by first replacement `a1b` which prevents it from being used in `b2c`. [Look-around](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) is necessary in this case.

Comment: Also Java ``\`` is special character in String so to create String representing this literal you will need to write it as `"\\"` which means that `\d` regex needs to be written as `"\\d"`. Last thing is not actually a problem but maybe improvement, anyway to negate `\d` you don't need to write it as `[^\d]`, you can simply use `\D`.